# Flutter: Incorrect ListTile continuously deleted. (with firestore)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

file A

```
StreamBuilder<List<MemoModel>> memoList() {
    return StreamBuilder<List<MemoModel>>(
                stream: memoNetworkRepository.getMemosFromSpecificUser(userModel.userkey),
                builder: (context, memos){
                  if(memos.hasData){
                    if (memos.data.length != 0){
                      return SafeArea(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: memos.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index){
                            return memocard(userModel: userModel, memoModel: memos.data[index],);
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
                  else{
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                },
              );
  }
```

file B (`getMemosFromSpecificUser`)

```
Stream<List<MemoModel>> getMemosFromSpecificUser(String userKey){
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(COLLECTION_MEMOS).where(KEY_USERKEY, isEqualTo: userKey).orderBy(KEY_MEMOTIME, descending: true).snapshots().transform(toMemos);
  }
```

file C (Part of `memocard`)

```
SimpleDialogOption(
              child: Center(child: Text("Delete", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
              onPressed: (){
                memoNetworkRepository.removememo(memoModel.memoKey);
              },
            )
```

file D (`removememo`)

```
Future<void> removememo(String memoKey){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(COLLECTION_MEMOS).doc(memoKey).delete();
  }
```

This is my code. I want to delete specific `memocard`. So When I delete specific `memocard`, delete is succesful. But deleted ones doesn't disappear. Only the bottom one of list disappears. This situation is resolved when leave and come in on this page. But I want resolved this situation without leaving this page. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: To look into this, can you please provide comments in your code? Maybe there is a logic error.